# Build Electron app

Tags: javascript, electron

I'm trying to build a setup file in Electron with **electron-builder**
but it's always giving me an error. I'm running in the latest version on electron, npm and nodejs.

```
 {
  "name": "whatsapp",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "WhatsApp software",
  "main": "main.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "electron .",
    "pack": "build --dir",
    "dist": "build"
  },
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "git+https://github.com/TheNerdGuyLulu/WhatsApp.git"
  },
  "keywords": [
    "whatsapp"
  ],
  "author": "TheNerdGuyLulu",
  "license": "MIT",
  "devDependencies": {
    "electron": "^1.6.5",
    "electron-builder": "^17.0.3",
    "electron-packager": "^8.6.0"
  }
}
```

This is the error:

```
   D:\Programação\Projetos\ELECTRON\WhatsApp>npm run dist

> whatsapp@1.0.0 dist D:\Programação\Projetos\ELECTRON\WhatsApp
> build

No native production dependencies
Packaging for win32 x64 using electron 1.6.5 to dist\win-unpacked
⚠️  Application icon is not set, default Electron icon will be used
Building NSIS installer
  Packaging NSIS installer for arch x64
Error: C:\Users\Luís Chaves\AppData\Local\electron-builder\cache\nsis\nsis-3.0.1.10\Bin\makensis.exe exited with code 1
Output:
Command line defined: "APP_ID=com.electron.whatsapp"
Command line defined: "APP_GUID=aee039cb-0158-543a-a7b5-acca8f2097e8"
Command line defined: "PRODUCT_NAME=whatsapp"
Command line defined: "PRODUCT_FILENAME=whatsapp"
Command line defined: "APP_FILENAME=whatsapp"
Command line defined: "APP_DESCRIPTION=WhatsApp software"
Command line defined: "VERSION=1.0.0"
Command line defined: "COMPANY_NAME=TheNerdGuyLulu"
Command line defined: "PROJECT_DIR=D:\Programa��o\Projetos\ELECTRON\WhatsApp"
Command line defined: "BUILD_RESOURCES_DIR=D:\Programa��o\Projetos\ELECTRON\WhatsApp\build"
Command line defined: "APP_64=D:\Programa��o\Projetos\ELECTRON\WhatsApp\dist\whatsapp-1.0.0-x64.nsis.7z"
Command line defined: "APP_64_NAME=whatsapp-1.0.0-x64.nsis.7z"
Command line defined: "COMPRESSION_METHOD=7z"
Command line defined: "ONE_CLICK"
Command line defined: "RUN_AFTER_FINISH"
Command line defined: "MULTI_LANGUAGE_INSTALLER"
Command line defined: "COMPRESS=auto"
Command line defined: "BUILD_UNINSTALLER"
Command line defined: "UNINSTALLER_OUT_FILE=C:\Users\LUSCHA~1\AppData\Local\Temp\electron-builder-kztCbb\0-1-uninstaller.exe"
Processing config: C:\Users\Lu�s Chaves\AppData\Local\electron-builder\cache\nsis\nsis-3.0.1.10\nsisconf.nsh
Processing script file: "<stdin>" (ACP)

Error output:
!include: could not find: "UAC.nsh"
!include: error in script: "multiUser.nsh" on line 2
Error in script "<stdin>" on line 10 -- aborting creation process

NSIS script:
!addincludedir "D:\Programação\Projetos\ELECTRON\WhatsApp\node_modules\electron-builder\templates\nsis\include"
!addplugindir /x86-unicode "C:\Users\Luís Chaves\AppData\Local\electron-builder\cache\nsis-resources\nsis-resources-3.0.0\plugins\x86-unicode"
!addplugindir /x86-unicode "D:\Programação\Projetos\ELECTRON\WhatsApp\build\x86-unicode"
!include "C:\Users\LUSCHA~1\AppData\Local\Temp\electron-builder-kztCbb\0-2-messages.nsh"
Var startMenuLink
Var desktopLink

!include "common.nsh"
!include "MUI2.nsh"
!include "multiUser.nsh"
!include "allowOnlyOneInstallerInstance.nsh"

!ifdef INSTALL_MODE_PER_ALL_USERS
  !ifdef BUILD_UNINSTALLER
    RequestExecutionLevel user
  !else
    RequestExecutionLevel admin
  !endif
!else
  RequestExecutionLevel user
!endif

!ifdef ONE_CLICK
  !include "oneClick.nsh"
!else
  !include "boringInstaller.nsh"
!endif

!ifmacrodef customHeader
  !insertmacro customHeader
!endif

!ifdef BUILD_UNINSTALLER
  SilentInstall silent
!else
  Var appExe
!endif

Function .onInit
  !ifmacrodef preInit
    !insertmacro preInit
  !endif
  !ifdef BUILD_UNINSTALLER
    WriteUninstaller "${UNINSTALLER_OUT_FILE}"
    !insertmacro quitSuccess
  !else
    !insertmacro check64BitAndSetRegView

    !ifdef ONE_CLICK
      !insertmacro ALLOW_ONLY_ONE_INSTALLER_INSTANCE
    !else
      ${IfNot} ${UAC_IsInnerInstance}
        !insertmacro ALLOW_ONLY_ONE_INSTALLER_INSTANCE
      ${EndIf}
    !endif

    !insertmacro initMultiUser

    !ifmacrodef customInit
      !insertmacro customInit
    !endif
  !endif
FunctionEnd

!ifndef BUILD_UNINSTALLER
  !include "installUtil.nsh"
!endif

Section "install"
  !ifndef BUILD_UNINSTALLER
    !include "installSection.nsh"
  !endif
SectionEnd

!ifdef BUILD_UNINSTALLER
  !include "uninstaller.nsh"
!endif

npm ERR! Windows_NT 10.0.15063
npm ERR! argv "D:\\Programas\\nodejs\\node.exe" "D:\\Programas\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "run" "dist"npm ERR! node v7.9.0
npm ERR! npm  v4.2.0
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 4294967295
npm ERR! whatsapp@1.0.0 dist: `build`
npm ERR! Exit status 4294967295
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the whatsapp@1.0.0 dist script 'build'.
npm ERR! Make sure you have the latest version of node.js and npm installed.
npm ERR! If you do, this is most likely a problem with the whatsapp package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR!     build
npm ERR! You can get information on how to open an issue for this project with:
npm ERR!     npm bugs whatsapp
npm ERR! Or if that isn't available, you can get their info via:
npm ERR!     npm owner ls whatsapp
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Luís Chaves\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2017-04-24T00_01_13_272Z-debug.log
```

I'm driving crazy with this problem please help me

Answer (score 0):

Can you try adding the build property entry in package.json file as below, as this works for me:

```
{ 
     "build": {
        "extraFiles": [
          "some-internal-plugin-dist"
        ],
        "appId": "myCompany.myApp",
        "nsis": {
          "perMachine": true,
          "oneClick": false,
          "allowToChangeInstallationDirectory": true
        },
        "squirrelWindows": {},
        "files": [
          "electron.js",
          "www/**/*"
        ],
         "directories": {
        "buildResources": "www/build"
        },
        "appx": {
          "identityName": "myCompany.myApp",
          "publisher": "CN=number",
          "publisherDisplayName": "my publisher name",
          "applicationId": "myApp",
          "displayName": "myApp"
        },
        "win": {
          "certificateFile": "./certs/CordovaApp.wincert.pfx",
          "icon":  "www/build/win.ico",
          "publisherName": "my Company",
          "target": [
            {
              "target": "nsis",
              "arch": [
                "ia32"
              ]
            }
          ]
        },
        "nodeGypRebuild": "false",
        "npmRebuild": "false"
      }
    }
```

It needs to have the build configurations inside package.json file.